# Get datagrid rows from a Function of another class

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, datagrid

I've created a `datagrid` in a window. It's empty for now. On the top of the window I have two `TextBoxes` with *FirstName* and *LastName*. When I enter the First and Last Name it should connect to the Database, check if there's already a person with that name (one or many) and if that's the case, it should show the names along with a couple of other columns in the datagrid below.

The problem is, I suppose to have a Customer Class and in that class firstname, lastname and the function called `SearchNames()`, and that function should have the SQL Statement, and it´s connecting to the database, and checking if there are people with the name I typed in.

I have to call that function somehow from my window class, and I don't know how to connect datagrid and that function or how to connect the textboxes from my window with the Customer class's firstname and lastname. Or even to write the whole function for extracting the data to the end. I appreciate all the help you can give me. Thanks

Comment: I have been having same troubles. Sounds like you need to learn MVVM and data bindings. Why don't you start from googling or even searching here, on how to retrieve data from database, and write your function

Comment: This website is for [professional developers that have specific programming problems](http://stackoverflow.com/help), *not* total beginners that have no idea about the basics of programming. As such, I have voted to close this question for being too broad (asking too much).